# How to render any file format(doc,ppt,xls) into printable format in android?

Tags: android

I am developing a andoid application which need to print some documents.Documents may be in different format like docx,ppt,xls. Now how can i render that other format in printable format in android ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewers in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084318/viewers-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development, I think you should use `some third party library` or `open office source` for developing such kind of application.

Or you can also use `apache's doc4j open source project` for development. Some libraries are in .so format so you have to build it using NDK(JNI).

A demo example for reading .Doc file using apache.poi [reading data from the .Doc file by using Apache POI api](http://javamix.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/reading-data-from-the-doc-file-by-using-apache-poi-api/)

Comment: for android you have to do some modification in api's source code. And have a trick or idea how to use that extracted data. :-)

Comment: Which APIs are talking about ? Is it POI APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need one or more converters :)

Here are a couple of options:

- http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/android/
- http://www.quickoffice.com/quickoffice_pro_android/

This might be ideal for you:

- [GDocs for Android](http://sites.google.com/site/gdocsforandroid/)
- [Docs, DocX PDFs on your Android](http://www.yozzo.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=371%3adocs-docx-pdf-on-your-android-or-iphone-&catid=282%3amobile&Itemid=123&lang=en)

Comment: But I am not getting how to use ' Documents To Go' with android. Do you have any idea ?