# Preview image of text file in Android

Tags: android, text-files, thumbnails

I would like knowing if it's possible to obtain the preview image (**thumbnail**) of any text file in Android, like **PDF, DOC, TXT, PPT, PPTX, RSS or HTML**.
If the response is positive, how do I can make it?

I have the preview images of video and image files, and I want to obtain the same result for text files.

Thanks for your attention, greetings.

Comment: How would a preview image of a 100KB .txt file look like? How would the preview image of a 100 slide .ppt file look like?

Comment: The first page or slide ... as some messaging programs such as GMAIL or HOTMAIL, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This can be quite a problem since you need to handle every file type individually.

**TXT**, **RSS** and **HTML** are simple enough, you can just read them all like a text file and display the text on the screen (first X characters, for instance, either with a `TextView` or by manually drawing it in the `onDraw` method. However, if you want to render the HTML, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633988/generate-bitmap-from-html-in-android) question.

**PDF** is another story, you need some sort of rendering endine for that, you might want to look at [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/).

**RSS** and **HTML** Can work the same way as a normal TXT file.

**PPT**, **PPTX** and **DOC** will also need a custom renderer, you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816606/how-to-render-any-file-formatdoc-ppt-xls-into-printable-format-in-android) question.

Comment: All this is quite complex to manage, is there a simpler way to get the thumbnails? as in the case of images (ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail) or videos (ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail)

Comment: I'm afraid not. Maybe if there exists a library that puts all of this together, but I couldn't find anything.